# How I can get parts of seconds of the current time in accuracy 10^-9 c++?

Tags: c++, time

L want to make a random generator using parts of seconds.
So I need to get the current time(only parts of seconds) in accuracy 10^-9
How I can do that using c++?

Comment: What do you mean by "the current time(only parts of seconds) in accuracy 10^-9"?

Comment: if you used stop watch you'd notice that there is two numbers for minutes two numbers for seconds and two numbers for part of second.

Comment: I don't know if i was clear but for example 2.69 indicate to 2 seconds and 0.69 of a second. I need this part of second only but in accurency of 10^-9

Comment: 10^-9 is nano seconds I don't think any PC clock is this accurate.  You will be lucky to get milli second precision (10^-6).

Comment: If you want a random number generator, then use one of the ones that already exist (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead of trying to hack one together yourself - and in any case, don't base it on something as predictable as time.

Comment: time is not predictible,if you take stopclock and suddenly  stopped for five time you wont get the same number (a part of a second)

Comment: The question of getting true random numbers is really complicated. May be you want to use your OS-provided random generator like `/dev/random` in *Nix? This uses a lot more than seconds for the entropy an usually is cryptographically secure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it smells like XY problem. What the purpose of this randomness?

Answer (score -1):

Use `std::chrono` to obtain high precisions:
Sample code:

```
auto time_begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();
/* code to test ...  */
auto time_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();
auto total = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-begin).count();
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` provides the accuracy that the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Mattia F:your code give me difference between two clock.
that should be approximately constant.I need a random generator, for that i wanted to take part of a second.

Comment: You can check `std::chrono::duration_values::min` to determine the smallest time tick interval available. However, this may not provide the entropy needed which is reduced if ticks have any predictability or uneven distribution probability.

Comment: Don't trust boost::chrono! I have seen it produce even worse accuracy than the regular GetTickCount() or similar.